# Dataframe column value using max() function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I am trying to create a column called "Threshold" where the values are determined by calculation `df['column']/30**0.5` , but I want this column to have a minimum value of 0.2. So if the calculation is below 0.2, I want the column value to be 0.2.

For example:
df['column2'] = `(df['column']/30)**0.5` or 0.2 (which ever number is larger).

This is what I have currently:

```
df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'] = df['Historical_Average'].rolling(window=15).mean()
df['Threshold'] = max((((df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'])/30)**0.5), 0.2)
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html?highlight=maximum#numpy.maximum):

```
df['Threshold'] = np.maximum((((df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'])/30)**0.5), 0.2)
```

Or [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) with `lower` parameter:

```
df['Threshold'] = (((df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'])/30)**0.5).clip(lower=0.2)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Historical_MovingAverage_15':[.21,2,3]})
df['Threshold'] = np.maximum((((df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'])/30)**0.5), 0.2)
print (df)
   Historical_MovingAverage_15  Threshold
0                         0.21   0.200000
1                         2.00   0.258199
2                         3.00   0.316228
```

**Detail**:

```
print ((((df['Historical_MovingAverage_15'])/30)**0.5))
0    0.083666
1    0.258199
2    0.316228
Name: Historical_MovingAverage_15, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use .clip() since I don't need to import another library. Works perfectly.

Comment: Filtering can also be done with apply: ```df[df["column"].apply(lambda x: return x >= 0.2)]```